# shortcut the statement

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

Can you help me with this statement 
*
put the English statement of the following proverb, not more than 6 words

> Failures are divided into two classes - those who thought and never
>   did, and those who did and never though

*
I must write it with only six words , how I Can do it without change the meaning of the whole 
statement
plz help me 
Thank in advance to all

Comment: Think efficaciously, act thoughtfully, or fail.

Comment: Failures think inefficaciously or act unthoughtfully.

Comment: Saddam: The title (probably) contains a typo, but since you are not a native speaker, I want to point out that the word you meant was **shortcut**, not "_shurtcut_".

Answer (score 2):

Unrealised thoughts; unthoughtful acts - both fail.

Answer (score 0):

The author of this proverb failed, because he or she didn't recognize the third class of failure: those who do not think *and* do not act.

This logical simplification lets us say it in fewer than six words, such as: "thought plus action prevent failure", or the imperative "think and act, or fail".